# Electron builder icon is not showing on MAC

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am using electron-builder to build a dmg for mac version. Current version I use is 7.14.2 . I add build/icon.icns file which is 1024x1024 size, but after the build I see default EBP icon. I also set dmg icon which is showing on the top window panel when I have to move my app to Applications folder, but not on Application icon itself.

What I am doing wrong, the icon size? Or should I load icon through my BrowserWindow?

Thanks,
Tadas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for this issue. It seems that the problem was with my MacOS cache. MacOS have Icon Services Cache, so whenever you build something with one icon next time it won't change icon to new one because of cache.

Solution:

Use OnyX software for Mac to clean up Icon Services Cache. User > IconServices > Execute.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution I found was to update to the latest `electron-builder`, as this issue was apparently fixed in version 8.4.1.

There was a fix for this exact issue. The issue show how some attempts were made to fix it but I found updating worked a treat
https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/840